# "Including me" vs "Including myself"

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, reflexives

> - Many of them, including me, have similar thoughts about that.
> - Many Koreans including myself weren't concerned about them at all.

I'm studying English and wondering how different they are.
Could you guys let me know?

Answer (score 4):

The use of [reflexive pronouns](https://www.thoughtco.com/reflexive-pronouns-in-english-1211140) — compounds of a personal pronoun (*my, your, our; him, her, it, them*) and *-self/selves* — is grammatical only (1) when the subject and an object are the same:

> 07.09.2016 ·Tiger [Woods] found *himself* in this situation because he kept falling into the same trap: He didn't give [*himself*](https://ftw.usatoday.com/2016/09/tiger-woods-comeback-back-injury-safeway-open-pga-tour-return-date) enough time to recover, came back too soon, and re-injured *himself*. — USA Today

or (2) when used for emphasis following a noun or pronoun (in bold):

> Perhaps because we [***ourselves***](https://books.google.de/books?id=ZYU9tyb4K2wC&pg=PA77&dq=%22we+ourselves%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiztq_3mL_cAhWqF5oKHW27CW8Q6AEIRTAH) have become bored with *ourselves*? Is man ***himself*** now supposed to have become bored with *himself*? — Martin Heidegger,  *The Fundamental Concepts of Metaphysics: World, Finitude, Solitude*, 1995.

The use of *myself* instead of *I/me* has never been limited to those of low education or social status:

> Her Royal Highness, her lady of honor, my sister, and [*myself*](https://books.google.de/books?id=3-TeOZLGsJoC&pg=RA3-PA35&dq=%22Sister+and+myself+went%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTgP3Fob_cAhUCJJoKHeZ8AEkQ6AEIUzAJ), went up in a sort of car on two wheels, drawn by oxen, which is the best equipage the country affords ; the rest of the household were on foot.  — George IV, King of Great Britain and Ireland (“with” [John Wilson Croker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wilson_Croker)),  *A Letter from the King to His People*, 1821, 35.

Particularly in the structure in question, as well as the allied *myself included*, even educated elites may substitute *myself*  in *including me*. A [Google Books NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=myself+included%2Cincluding+myself%2Cincluding+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmyself%20included%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cincluding%20myself%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cincluding%20me%3B%2Cc0) shows that the grammatically incorrect *myself* rivals the correct expression, which along with the equally incorrect *myself included* shows a considerable increase in frequency since the 1960s:

[image]

I myself (see what I did there?) never use *including myself*, but in less formal speech have no qualms about *myself included*. I think of it as one of those illogical but thoroughly idiomatic expressions such as *It's me*, but try to avoid it in formal writing.

Answer (score 2):

Reflexive pronouns such as "myself" and "yourself" are supposed to be used when the subject and object of a sentence or statement are the same. You clothe yourself, I wash myself. Strictly speaking that's how it should be used.

However these reflexive pronouns are also used in other ways, including to convey emphasis:

myself
b. Used for emphasis: I myself was certain of the facts.
[American Heritage Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/myself)

This dictionary has a helpful usage note:

> Usage Note: The -self pronouns, such as myself, yourselves, and
>   herself, are sometimes used as emphatic substitutes for personal
>   pronouns, as in He was an enthusiastic fisherman like myself...
>
> A majority of the Usage Panel dislikes them, though resistance has
>   been eroding over the years...
>   [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/myself)

Check the link for the full explanation.

In your sentences "Including me." is correct. "Including myself" may be correct depending how pedantic or prescriptive you want to be. In my opinion a strict rule of grammar shouldn't preclude us in using speech to have as many subtleties as possible, and "Including myself" has a tone of emphasis to it, as for example it may carry a meaning of "me too/me also".